# Update HTML automatically when receiving HTTP GET request from a source that is not the HTML page.

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Trying to figure out how i can update an HTML table each time i get a HTTP GET request. The trouble is the request is not coming from the HTML, it is from a 3rd party. I need to append the table each time a request comes in, sort of a dashboard.

lets say i have a function to add A and B. My server gets a GET request with {A : 1, B: 2}. My code gets that and console logs {A : 1, B : 2, total: 3}.

What i can't figure out is how to have my html auto update to display the result. I was able to write it to mongo, and add a refresh button to the web page and when i click it it updates my page. 
I want the page to update each time a GET request comes in.

Comment: How would your client know that a request came to your server? You'd have to implement some kind of polling mechanism.

Comment: What do you mean with "a GET request comes in"? Is it coming in in the back-end or the front-end? Are you calling the node back-end from an angular front-end?

Comment: Is this an XHR request from client? You may just need a success callback on the request that will update the page (either from receiving data from the request itself or from polling again once success is achieved).

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. The way you wrote it it *might* mean you want to provide some PUSH-behaviour which is not part of the "regular" http protocol. Please specify what you expect to change in a client and to what degree that change should be "automatic".